# Having troubles in cloned fields with javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm having troubles in javascript function in a cloned fieldset.

This is my JS code:

```
$("a#add").click(function(){
    $('<fieldset class="articulos" id="'+ i +'"><input name="articulo[' + i + '][nombre]" id="art_nombre" value="" /><input name="articulo[' + i + '][cantidad]" class="art_cantidad" value="" /><input name="articulo[' + i + '][preciou]" class="art_preciou" value="" /><input name="articulo[' + i + '][descuento]" class="art_desc" value="" /><input name="articulo[' + i + '][precio]" class="art_precio" value="" /></fieldset> ').appendTo(".detalle");
    return false;
    $('.detalle fieldset .art_cantidad, .detalle fieldset .art_preciou, .detalle fieldset .art_desc').on('input',function() {
        var qty = parseInt($('.detalle fieldset .art_cantidad').val());
        var price = parseFloat($('.detalle fieldset .art_preciou').val());
        var desc = parseFloat($('.detalle fieldset .art_desc').val());
        if($('.detalle fieldset .art_desc').val()==''){
            $('.detalle fieldset .art_precio').val((qty * price ? qty * price : 0).toFixed(2));
        } else {
            $('.detalle fieldset .art_precio').val(((qty * price ? qty * price : 0) - desc).toFixed(2));
        }
    });

    i++;


});
```

Here's my html code:

```
<div class="detalle">
                        <fieldset class="articulos" id="0">
                            <input name="articulo[0][nombre]" id="art_nombre" value="nombre" />
                            <input name="articulo[0][cantidad]" id="art_cantidad" value="" />
                            <input name="articulo[0][preciou]" id="art_preciou" value="" />
                            <input name="articulo[0][cantidad]" id="art_desc" value="" />
                            <input name="articulo[0][precio]" id="art_precio" value="" readonly="readonly" />
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <a id="add">Agregar</a>
```

The problem is that when I clone the fields the function works only for the first fieldset. I think it is because I am not identifying either the class name or something like that.

Thank you very much.

Here's my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8hsWu/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several errors here.

1. In delegation. You need to use

   ```
   $(".articulos").on("input", ":input", function(){ ... });
   ```
2. You are creating several elements with same id, you need to add your `i` to elements id as well.
3. You don't specify exactly what elements do you take values from.

   ```
   var qty = parseInt($('.detalle fieldset .art_cantidad').val());
   ```

This is wrong, and don't point to your exact element. what you need to do is

```
var qty = parseInt($(this).parent().children(".art_candidat").val());
```

This applies to all of your elements with value.

All this you should apply outside of `$("#add").click()` area and use creation only to make new fieldset.

To sum all values from `.art_precio` you can do:

```
var sum_precio = 0;
$(".detalle").find(".art_precio").each(function(){
   sum_precio += parseInt(this.value);
});
```

Plain javascript `this.value` works much faster than `$(this).val()` and does the same.

Comment: how i've to do to add all the fields who have class name ".art_precio"?

Comment: Something what do you mean by "add all the fields"? Sum their value?

Comment: Edited answer for your second question.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is not well defined classes and id should be something like:

```
<input class="campo" name="articulo[0][cantidad]" id="art_cantidad0" value="" />
```

this may be the solution

http://jsfiddle.net/n2h8a/